# PhD thesis Microsoft Word templates

Tags: phd, thesis

What "beautiful" looking PhD thesis Microsoft Word templates do you recommend using?

Comment: LAAAAAATEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEX

Comment: Additionally, thats generally not up to you. Universities tend to have VERY strict regulations on how the thesis should look like.

Comment: Compare Google Image searches for [beautiful Microsoft Word template](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=beautiful+microsoft+word+template) and [beautiful LaTeX template](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=beautiful+latex+template).

Answer (score 4):

To amplify the comment by Ander, you should ask around your university, look its website, ask the office where you are supposed to submit, ask other recent graduates or ABD students, and find out what is being used by others. Your university will have formatting requirements, and someone will have a Word template that conforms to those requirements.